# Grails 3.3.11 and Spring boot actuator do not work for health endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, grails, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to configure Spring boot actuator in my grails 3.3.11 rest-api application, in order to have health information about it. But when I access {base_url}/cmbid/actuator/health, I receive a 404 response like that

```
2021-08-25 15:13:18.980  WARN --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/cmbid/actuator/health] in DispatcherServlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Below, I can show you some relevante information.
Grails version 3.3.11
It is a rest-api profile application

In my build.gradle file I configured like that

```
dependencies {
     compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
}
```

In my application.yml file I configured like that.

```
endpoints:
    health:
        enabled: true
    web:
        exposure:
        include: health
    jmx:
        enabled: true
        unique-names: true
```

I have no idea where the problem is, but in my grails 4.0.3 it works as expected. The only defference, is that, in Grails 4.0.3, the application.yml gets a management entry, like that.

```
management:
    endpoints:
        enabled-by-default: true
    endpoint:
        health:
            show-details : always
```

I removed management entry from grails 3.3.11 application because it does not work and I saw in internet documentation, that if you put endpoints entry in the root of application.yml it would work.

Unfortunately, I have no idea about what is happening.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might have endpoints disabled. Could you please verify that the following configuration is set to `true`:

```
endpoints:
    enabled: true
```

I just tested with a Grails 3.3.11 REST API application, which correctly returns the response as:

curl -XGET localhost:8080/health

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```